# How to maintain Session Management in Servlets

Tags: servlets, httpsession, session-management

The Hidden Form Field does not involve in maintaining a user's session.

Then why Hidden Form Field are used in Session Management in Servlets.

Comment: Nope. That's not true. See abovelinked duplicate how "Session Management in Servlets" actually works. You're most probably confusing the "Hidden Form Field" thing from some other framework. Probably JSF? Or Spring MVC? etc. Try googling the name of that hidden field to get answers why that framework uses the particular hidden field. This has in turn got nothing to do with Servlet native session management.